# Not able to set the default namespace in Android XmlSerializer

Tags: android, xml-serialization

How do I add a default namespace with no prefix using XMLSerializer.

I am using org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer on Android.

```
 XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
 xmlSerializer.startTag("efgh", "abcd");
```

is giving `<n0:abcd xmlns:n0="efgh">`

but i want it to be

```
<abcd xmlns="efgh">
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the namespace without prefix can be seen as an attribute.

so this is code:

```
xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "abcd");
xmlSerializer.attribute(null, "xmlns", "efgh");
xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "abcd");
```

Comment: What `null` means ?

Comment: @faisal1208 to see:https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's what the XmlSerializer.setPrefix(String prefix, String namespace) is for:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer.html#setPrefix(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer.html#setPrefix%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Have you tried using that?

It binds the prefix to the namespace. The call is valid for the next element including child elements.

**NOTE**: this method MUST be called directly before startTag() and if anything but startTag() or setPrefix() is called next there will be exception.